# Multidimensional array key value replacement

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array I'm trying to change this arrays's some keys but function fails for arrays which are recursive.

What could be problem

Any one can fix this?

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'lines',
        array(
            'tag' => 'div',
            'repeat' => array(
                'tag' => 'div',
                 array(
                    'tag' => 'span',
                    'style' => 'margin:10px; padding:10px',
                    'key' => 'title',
                ),
                'key' => 'subject',
            )
        )
    )
);



function update_recursively($array, $key = '', $value = array()) {
    //print_r($array); print_r($value);
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === $key){ 
            $array[$k] = $value;
        }
        elseif (is_array($v))
            $array[$k] = update_recursively($v);
    }
    return $array;
}

print_r(update_recursively($array, 'repeat', array('d' => 'a')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to pass `2nd` and `3rd` parameter to inner function call:

```
function update_recursively($array, $key = '', $value = array()) {
    //print_r($array); print_r($value);
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === $key){ 
            $array[$k] = $value;
        } elseif (is_array($v)) {
            $array[$k] = update_recursively($v, $key, $value);    // Here
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much u_mulder I think I been tired.